# Give user total control to all subsites

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepointadmin

I am in a sharepoint application that was already built using MOSS 2007.

At this application my user has total control on the admnistration and is a administrator on the root website `http://rootwebsite`, but not on the subsites.

I used the Check Effective Permissions from the Sharepoint Administrations Toolkit and is showing that my user has:

```
Total Control, Limited Access | Given Directly 
Contribute, Limited Access | Subsite 2
Contribute, Limited Access | Subsite 3
Contribute, Limited Access | Subsite 4
.
.
```

How can I make this user to have a total control of all subsites ?

Comment: So much wrong with your question :-) "Collaboration" is not a permission. Did you mean "Contribute" or do you have custom permissions? Same goes for "Total control". You cannot edit pages in the _layouts folder like searchresults.aspx, hence there is no edit button.

Comment: Sorry, is because I translated from portuguese straight. How to make it to redirect to the search results page you want ?